# Posterior distribution of shape & rate parameter in Poisson-Gamma Mixture

Tags: self-study, bayesian, poisson-distribution, posterior, mixture-distribution

Currently I'm struggling to handle the following question.

---

> Suppose $x_i,(i=1,2,\dots,n)$ follows Poisson distribution:
> $$p(x_i|\theta) = \frac{\theta^{x_i}e^{-\theta}}{x_i!}, \quad x_i\in\mathbb N,\quad \theta>0.$$
> If $\theta|(\alpha,\beta)\sim\Gamma(\alpha,\beta)$, we have
> $$p(x_i|\alpha,\beta) = \binom{\alpha+x_i-1}{x_i}\Bigl(\frac{\beta}{\beta+1}\Bigr)^{\alpha}\Bigl(\frac{1}{\beta+1}\Bigr)^{x_i},\quad \alpha,\beta>0.$$
> Under these facts, obtain the posterior distribution of $(\alpha,\beta)$ with a noninformative prior $p(\alpha,\beta)\propto1$.

---

I tried to solve it as follows: (letting $\mathbf x := (x_1,\dots,x_n)$)
$$\begin{aligned}
p(\alpha,\beta|\mathbf x) &\propto p(\alpha,\beta)p(\mathbf x|\alpha,\beta) \\
&\propto1*\prod_{i=1}^n\binom{\alpha+x_i-1}{x_i}\Bigl(\frac{\beta}{\beta+1}\Bigr)^{\alpha}\Bigl(\frac{1}{\beta+1}\Bigr)^{x_i} \\
&=\Biggl\{\prod_{i=1}^n\binom{\alpha+x_i-1}{x_i}\Biggr\}\Biggl(\frac{\beta}{\beta+1}\Biggr)^{n\alpha}\Biggl(\frac{1}{\beta+1}\Biggr)^{\sum_i x_i}.
\end{aligned}$$
At first, I guessed $(\alpha,\beta)|\mathbf x$ follows some similar form to negative binomial distribution, but I failed to get (my desired) result.

So, I want to check whether my estimation was wrong, and if not, how could I finish the equation above. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Since $\alpha$ and $\beta$ aren't restricted to be integers, the posterior clearly can't be some negative binomial distribution.

Comment: Yes $\alpha$ is not integer (which doesn't make the expression negative binomial technically), but I meant that the form of the expressions I presented looked similar to the negative binomial (so I just used the term 'negative binomial' without clear denotation).

Comment: What was your desired result, the one you failed to get?  There's nothing wrong with your algebra.

Comment: Then, you think there is nothing more to proceed from my last calculation? "desired" means there must be better closed form of the posterior distribution.

Comment: The problem is $\alpha$; if you condition on that, then $\beta$ has a $\beta'$ distribution.   Note also that the $x_i$ in the denominator of the $\beta$ function can go away, and you can write the product term as $\Pi_{i=1}^N\Pi_{j=0}^{x_i-1}(\alpha + j)$, which doesn't help you much notationally but might be computationally faster.

Comment: Ah, ok I see. Thank you for your help!